# XDoc Xml special characters wrong interpretation

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML that is created by a 3rd party app, and special characters (umlauts in my case) are encoded this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TAG>
    Gepr&#195;&#188;ft
</TAG>
```

I am reading the Xml using this code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"<path_to_xml_file>", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(textReader);

        var value = xDoc.Root.Value;
    }
}
```

The resulting string is

> GeprÃ¼ft

while it actually should be

> Geprüft

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like something's wrong on the other side. &#195; NCR stands for `Ã` char, and &#188; for `¼`. So, it is decoded correctly.

Comment: See following webpage : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Encoding is wrong. Try this :             var stream = new FileStream(@"<path_to_xml_file>", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var m_stream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: if you need `Geprüft` as output, input should be `Gepr&#252;ft`, for the input `Gepr&#195;&#188;ft`, output  `GeprÃ¼ft` is correct. First You may need to check the inputs and outputs of 3rd party application and confirm that tool is working fine or not.

Comment: Damith: I think the characters are being changed due to an encoding issue.  The default ASCII encoding we change MSB creating this issue.  Using UTF8 encoding will solve issue.

Comment: jdweng: I don't see any real difference in your code except the missing 3rd paramter. Doesn't change anything with the result though, unfortunately.

Comment: Stream class default to Ascii encoding that removed non printable characters and/or change characters.  It looks like characters are changing the from : U+00FC (252) to: U+00C3 (195).  You may want to try Unicode in stead of UTF8.  You may also have a big endian, little endian issue with bytes reverse.  The issue may be with the data before you actually get the file and another application is creating the error.